# How to preserve alphabetical order of keys when sorting a hash by the value

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash, key-value, alphabetical

beginner here. My first question. Go easy on me.

Given the following hash:

```
pets_ages = {"Eric" => 6, "Harry" => 3, "Georgie" => 12, "Bogart" => 4, "Poly" => 4,
        "Annie" => 1, "Dot" => 3}
```

and running the following method:

```
pets_ages.sort {|x, y| x[1] <=> y[1]}.to_h
```

the following is returned:

```
{
      "Annie" => 1,
        "Dot" => 3,
      "Harry" => 3,
       "Poly" => 4,
     "Bogart" => 4,
       "Eric" => 6,
    "Georgie" => 12
}
```

You will notice the hash is nicely sorted by the value, as intended. What I'd like to change is the ordering of the keys, so that they remain alphabetical in the case of a tie. Notice "Dot" and "Harry" are correct in that regard, but for some reason "Poly" and "Bogart" are not. My theory is that it is automatically sorting the keys by length in the case of a tie, and not alphabetically. How can I change that?

Comment: I would be careful expecting keys to be in a given order using Hashes.  Unless you are sure your using ActiveSupport::OrderedHash or some other library that ensures key ordering.  Hashes are supposed to be key-based lookups.  There isn't supposed to be an order.  If you need the order, leave it as an array.

Comment: `pets_ages.sort_by { |k, v| [v, k] }` or `pets_ages.sort_by(&:reverse)` should work

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom In Ruby, Hashes are explicitly ordered as of 1.9+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In many languages, Hashes/Dicts aren't ordered, because of how the are implemented under the covers. Ruby 1.9+ is nice enough to guarantee ordering.

You can do this in a single pass - Ruby allows you to sort by arbitrary criteria.

```
# Given
pets_ages = {"Eric" => 6, "Harry" => 3, "Georgie" => 12, "Bogart" => 4, "Poly" => 4, "Annie" => 1, "Dot" => 3}

# Sort pets by the critera of "If names are equal, sort by name, else, sort by age"
pets_ages.sort {|(n1, a1), (n2, a2)| a1 == a2 ? n1 <=> n2 : a1 <=> a2 }.to_h

# => {"Annie"=>1, "Dot"=>3, "Harry"=>3, "Bogart"=>4, "Poly"=>4, "Eric"=>6, "Georgie"=>12}
```

Hash#sort will return an array of `[k, v]` pairs, but those `k, v` pairs can be sorted by any criteria you want in a single pass. Once we have the sorted pairs, we turn it back into a Hash with `Array#to_h` (Ruby 2.1+), or you can use `Hash[sorted_result]` in earlier versions, as Beartech points out.

You could get as complex as you want in the sort block; if you're familiar with Javascript sorting, Ruby actually works the same here. The `<=>` method returns -1, 0, or 1 depending on how the objects compare to each other. #sort just expects one of those return values, which tells it how the two given values relate to each other. You don't even have to use `<=>` at all if you don't want to - something like this is equivalent to the more compact form:

```
pets_ages.sort do |a, b|
  if a[1] == b[1]
    if a[0] > b[0]
      1
    elsif a[0] < b[0]
      -1
    else
      0
    end
  else
    if a[1] > b[1]
      1
    elsif a[1] < b[1]
      -1
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, as long as you always return something in the set (-1 0 1), your sort function can do whatever you want, so you can compose them however you'd like. However, such verbose forms are practically never necessary in Ruby, because of the super handy <=> operator!

As Stefan points out, though, you have a BIG shortcut here: Array#<=> is nice enough to [compare each entry between the compared arrays](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E). This means that we can do something like:

```
pets_ages.sort {|a, b| a.reverse <=> b.reverse }.to_h
```

This takes each [k, v] pair, reverses it into [v, k], and uses Array#<=> to compare it. Since you need to perform this same operation on each [k, v] pair compared, you can shortcut it even further with #sort_by

```
pets_ages.sort_by {|k, v| [v, k] }.to_h
```

What this does is for each hash entry, it passes the key and value to the block, and the return result of the block is what is used to compare this [k, v] pair to other entries. Since comparing [v, k] to another [v, k] pair will give us the result we want, we just return an array consisting of [v, k], which sort_by collects and sorts the original [k, v] pairs by.

Comment: You could write the last one as `pets_ages.sort_by(&:reverse).to_h`.

Answer (score 1):

As Philip pointed out, hashes were not meant to preserve order, though I think in the latest Ruby they might. But let's say they don't. Here's an array based solution that could then be re-hashed:

**Edit** here it is in a one-liner:

```
 new_pets_ages = Hash[pets_ages.sort.sort_by {|a| a[1]}]
```

previous answer:

```
pets_ages = {"Eric" => 6, "Harry" => 3, "Georgie" => 12, "Bogart" => 4, "Poly" => 4,
    "Annie" => 1, "Dot" => 3}

arr = pets_ages.sort

# [["Annie", 1], ["Bogart", 4], ["Dot", 3], ["Eric", 6], ["Georgie", 12],
#    ["Harry", 3], ["Poly", 4]]

new_arr = arr.sort_by {|a| a[1]}

#[["Annie", 1], ["Dot", 3], ["Harry", 3], ["Bogart", 4], ["Poly", 4], ["Eric", 6],
#    ["Georgie", 12]]
```

And finally to get a hash back:

```
h = Hash[new_arr]

#{"Annie"=>1, "Dot"=>3, "Harry"=>3, "Bogart"=>4, "Poly"=>4, "Eric"=>6, 
#   "Georgie"=>12}
```

So when we sort a hash, it gives us an array of arrays with the items sorted by the original keys. Then we sort that array of arrays by the second value of each, and since it's a lazy sort, it only shifts them if need be. Then we can send it back to a hash. I'm sure there's a trick way to do a two-pass sort in one line but this seems pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know few methods of ruby for sorting that you have used. So I would not explain it you in detail rather keep it very simple one liner for you. Here is your answer:

```
pets_ages.sort.sort_by{|pets| pets[1]}.to_h
```

Thanks